# How to correct update stock quantity with stored procedure Firebird multi store?

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures, firebird

How to correct update stock quantity with stored procedure Firebird multi store?

I have 5 table

1) JournalMast

```
Id
DateOperation
BatchNo
Type Operation (1-Purchase, 2-Sale,3-Return Sale,4-movement beetween store,5-Correction Adjustment)
FromStoreID  (In purchase case China,Turkey etc)
ToStoreID    (In purchase case set Main Store ID)
UserID
IsExecute    (Yes,NO)  if yes i should insert or update adjust item balance
```

2) JournalDetail

```
Id
JournalMastID
BatchNOID     (This Column need when movement or sale or return  select user which batchNO we will)   
ItemsID
QTY
Amount
```

3) JournalPayment

```
Id
JournalMastID
DatePayment
Amount
IsPayed yes no
```

4) BatchTable

```
ID
IDPurchase  (ID JournalMast when purchase) 
StoreID
ItemsID
Qty
Cost
```

5) ItemsTable

```
ID
Name
```

I need update this table correctly when updating journalmaster or journalDetail or JournalPayment because Cost I will calculate with payment table.

My solution now

1. Create 3 procedures for Master  Table Insert/Update/Delete/
2. Create 3 procedures for Detail  Table Insert/Update/Delete/
3. Create 3 procedures for Payment Table Insert/Update/Delete/

One procedure for adjustment BatchTable

I call from client side like this

```
try
    StartTransaction
       Call insert procedure for masterTable returning ID
       Loop   
         Call insert procedure for DetailTableTable passing MasterID 
       end loop
       Call procedure for adjustment BatchTable
    CommitTransaction
except
  RollbackTransaction 
end
```

Am I doing this the right way?   I want without triggers doit but how i dont know..

I will add one column for all table  that means colstate rows (inserted or deleted)

> Example:    User purchase on 01.01.2016  from china to mainwarehouse
>   isexecuted = yes

```
01.01.2016   Item A  10 qty  10$   100$  inserted
01.01.2016   Item B  10 qty  10$   100$  inserted    
01.01.2016   Item C  10 qty  10$   100$  inserted
```

> Now i should insert batchtable for tracking FIFO because user check
>   isexecuted = yes

```
   Item A  10 qty  10$   100$  Mainwarehouse   idpurchase 1
   Item B  10 qty  10$   100$  Mainwarehouse   idpurchase 1
   Item C  10 qty  10$   100$  Mainwarehouse   idpurchase 1
```

> Now user when moveto Item A from mainwarehous to other store
>   isexecuted = yes

```
03.01.2016   Item A  1 qty  10$   10$  inserted BatchNOID = idpurchase 1
```

> i should change qty in batch table

```
  Item A  10 qty   9$   100$  Mainwarehouse   idpurchase 1
   Item A  1  qty   1$   10$  Store            idpurchase 1
```

> now user want to change this movement want to change field isexecuted
>   = NO

In this case how adjustment?

Comment: This question is simply not on topic.  What you are asking is not at all clear, but even should this be fixed it is still too broad and entirely opinion based.

Comment: I think you shoul use triggers and do your updates from triggers. In this case your client application just do insert/update/delete on table and the trigger do all other work.

Comment: Trigger i dont want because trigger user can disable so calculated being wron

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem, the solution is perform more StoredProcudure in a single transaction. I've dealt with something similar. I have 2 tables: "Order", "OrderItem", see. example.
PS: DBAdapter is our special class that wraps the opening of the connection / transaction...

```
public int Insert(Objednavka obj)
    {
      int newID = -1;
      try
      {
        dataAdapter.CreateTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("PROC_TAB_OBJEDNAVKAINS"))    
        {
          cmd.Connection = dataAdapter.Conn;
          cmd.Transaction = dataAdapter.Transaction;
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INID_FIRMAOBJEDNATEL.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_FIRMAOBJEDNATEL == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_FIRMAOBJEDNATEL));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INID_OSOBAOBJEDNATEL.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_OSOBAOBJEDNATEL == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_OSOBAOBJEDNATEL));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INID_UZIVATELPRIJAL.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_UZIVATELPRIJAL == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_UZIVATELPRIJAL));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INCISLOSTREDISKA.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.CISLOSTREDISKA));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INKOD.ToString(), FbDbType.VarChar, obj.KOD));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INSTAV.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.STAV));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INDATUMVYTVORENI.ToString(), FbDbType.TimeStamp, obj.DATUMVYTVORENI));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INDATUMPRIJETI.ToString(), FbDbType.TimeStamp, obj.DATUMPRIJETI));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.INPOZNAMKA.ToString(), FbDbType.VarChar, obj.POZNAMKA));

          cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaColumn.OUTID.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, ParameterDirection.Output, obj.ID));//OUTPUT parametr

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          newID = (int)cmd.Parameters["@" + ObjednavkaColumn.OUTID.ToString()].Value;
          obj.ID = newID;
        }
        if (obj.CollObjednavkaPolozka != null && obj.CollObjednavkaPolozka.Count > 0)
        {
          foreach (evotech.BussinesLayer.ObjednavkaPolozka polozka in obj.CollObjednavkaPolozka)
          {
            if (polozka.ObjectState == EnumObjectState.ToAdd)
            {
              polozka.ID_OBJEDNAVKA = newID;
              polozka.ID = ObjednavkaPolozka.Insert(polozka, dataAdapter);
            }
          }
        }
        if (dataAdapter != null)
        {
          if (dataAdapter.Transaction != null)
          {
            dataAdapter.Transaction.Commit();           
          }
          if (dataAdapter.Conn != null)
          {
            dataAdapter.CloseConnection();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (FbException ex)
      {
        if (dataAdapter != null)
        {
          if (dataAdapter.Transaction != null)
          {
            dataAdapter.Transaction.Rollback();
          }
          if (dataAdapter.Conn != null)
          {
            dataAdapter.CloseConnection();
          }
        }
        throw (new MyException(Strings.GetString("errorDBWrite"), ex));
      }
      return newID;
    }
```

and int the item we us same adapter with same open Connection+Transactions

```
public static int Insert(evotech.BussinesLayer.ObjednavkaPolozka obj, DBAdapter adapterOuter)
    {
      int ret = -1;
      using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("PROC_TAB_OBJEDNAVKAPOLOZKAINS"))
      {
        cmd.Connection = adapterOuter.Conn;
        cmd.Transaction = adapterOuter.Transaction;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! POŘADÍ ZDE DEFINOVANÝCH PARAMETRŮ MUSÍ BÝT STEJNÉ JAKO POŘADÍ VSTUPNÍCH PARAMETRŮ VE STOREDPROCEDUŘE  !!!!!!
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INID_OBJEDNAVKA.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_OBJEDNAVKA));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INID_MISTONAKLADKY.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_MISTONAKLADKY == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_MISTONAKLADKY));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INID_OSOBANAKLADKY1.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_OSOBANAKLADKY1 == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_OSOBANAKLADKY1));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INID_OSOBANAKLADKY2.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_OSOBANAKLADKY2 == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_OSOBANAKLADKY2));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INID_MISTOVYKLADKY.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_MISTOVYKLADKY == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_MISTOVYKLADKY));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INID_OSOBAVYKLADKY1.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_OSOBAVYKLADKY1 == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_OSOBAVYKLADKY1));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INID_OSOBAVYKLADKY2.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.ID_OSOBAVYKLADKY2 == -1 ? (object)DBNull.Value : obj.ID_OSOBAVYKLADKY2));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INTYPZBOZI.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, obj.TYPZBOZI));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INMNOZSTVIVAHA.ToString(), FbDbType.Decimal, obj.MNOZSTVIVAHA));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INMNOZSTVIOBJEM.ToString(), FbDbType.Decimal, obj.MNOZSTVIOBJEM));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INMNOZSTVIPALET.ToString(), FbDbType.Decimal, obj.MNOZSTVIPALET));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INMNOZSTVIKUS.ToString(), FbDbType.Decimal, obj.MNOZSTVIKUS));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INDATUMNAKLADKYOD.ToString(), FbDbType.TimeStamp, obj.DATUMNAKLADKYOD));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INDATUMNAKLADKYDO.ToString(), FbDbType.TimeStamp, obj.DATUMNAKLADKYDO));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INDATUMVYKLADKYOD.ToString(), FbDbType.TimeStamp, obj.DATUMVYKLADKYOD));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INDATUMVYKLADKYDO.ToString(), FbDbType.TimeStamp, obj.DATUMVYKLADKYDO));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.INPOPIS.ToString(), FbDbType.VarChar, obj.POPIS));

        cmd.Parameters.Add(DBUtils.CreateParameter(ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.OUTID.ToString(), FbDbType.Integer, ParameterDirection.Output, obj.ID));//OUTPUT parametr
        try
        {
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          ret = (int)cmd.Parameters["@" + ObjednavkaPolozkaColumn.OUTID.ToString()].Value;         
        }
        catch (FbException ex)
        {
          throw (new MyException(Strings.GetString("errorDBWrite"), ex));
        }
      }
      return ret;
    }
```

a

Comment: Ok for 2 tables I add two colum state (inserted or deleted) My problem how adjustment tracking batch no.